# How to filter HTTP requests based on body before they get to the server?

Tags: http, nginx, server, scalability

I'm using nginx to filter some requests before they get to my server, for the majority of it is of no interest, and I don't want to scale my servers to handle all requests, when I'm actually interested only in a fraction of them. Scaling nginx is cheaper.

Problem is nginx doesn't have (afaik) dynamic configuration, and we are doing only basic filtering right now, based on request parameters and origin IP address.

Is there any nginx-like software I can use with (possibly) both capabilities describe above (namely, dynamic configuration and all-powerful filtering, like regex on request body)?

I'm beginning to test OpenResty's lua scripting capabilities, but that looks like a mess workaroud to me. Any opinions on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually seems like OpenResty is a nice approach. More here: http://www.scalescale.com/scaling-cloudflares-massive-waf/.